# Trigger function in app.js from module.js

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

First time poster — please forgive (and call me out) on any formatting mistakes!

So let's say I have app.js, which requires `module.js`. In module.js I have an express server running that can receive simple webrequests (GET / POST). Is there any way for me to trigger functions in `app.js` when I receive a request in `module.js`?

Something along the lines of:

```
var webModule = require('./module.js')
webModule.on('GET', async function (req) {
    //do stuff with the request
});
```

The reason I'm not just putting the express server in `app.js` is that I want to run a certain amount of code to verify that the request is legitimate, and then re-use `module.js` in separate scripts to minimise the amount of code — and avoid having to update 5-6 scripts everytime I want to update the authentication process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Event system that exists in Node.js. If you set it up correctly you can emit an event on each call and have a listener respond to the event.

Example from the [Node.JS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events):

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', () => {
  console.log('an event occurred!');
});
myEmitter.emit('event');
```

In your case you could create a class that extends EventEmitter that you use in each request. This class can then emit an event when the request gets call which is then handled in your app.js file by setting up the listener.

Comment: This is really clever (and probably a lot better than the current idea I had), I'll try it! Thank you so much Cabbe!

Comment: Hope it works for the problem you wanted to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

I might have a solution, will take some time to code (since my question is *obviously* very simplified).

In `module.js`:

```js
var functionActions = {};

module.exports = {
    on : (async function(requestType, returnFunction){
      functionActions[requestType].do = returnFunction;
    });
 }
 
//general express code
app.get('*', function(req,res) { 
    if (verifyRequest(req) == 'okay'){ //authentication
        return functionActions['GET'].do();
    } else { //if the request is not authorised
        res.status(403).send('Stop trying to hack me you stupid hacker ಠ╭╮ಠ');
    }
});
```

I'll try it out and update this answer once I've figured out the potential kinks.